# C# Performance Comparison: Async vs Non-Async Text File IO operation via: Read\WriteAllLines vs Read\WriteAllLinesAsync

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, async-await

While I was dealing with relatively large text files I noticed something strange. Async Reading and writing is actually slower than the non-async reading:

E,g, executing this dummy code:

```
 var res1 = File.WriteAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", i), lines);
 var res2 = File.WriteAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}_bck.txt", i), lines);

 await res1;
 await res2;
```

is actually much slower than

```
  File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", i), lines);
  File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}_bck.txt", i), lines);
```

In theory the first approach should be faster, because the second writing should be stared before the first one is completed. The performance difference is about 100% for 15 ~25MBs files (10 vs 20 seconds).

I noticed the same behavior for ReadAllLines and ReadAllLinesAsync.

**Update:0** The main idea is to have all files processed after the completion of the function of TestFileWriteXXX functions. Therefore

```
Task.WhenAll(allTasks1); // Without await is not a valid option
```

**Update:1** I added read write using threads and it showed 50% improvement.
Here is the complete example:

**Update:2** I updated the code in order to eliminate the buffer generation overhead

```
        const int MaxAttempts = 5;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestFileWrite();
            TestFileWriteViaThread();
            TestFileWriteAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TestFileWrite()
        {
            Clear();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            Console.WriteLine( "Begin TestFileWrite");

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxAttempts; ++i)
            {
                TestFileWriteInt(i);
            }

            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TestFileWrite took: " + elapsedTime);
        }

        private static void TestFileWriteViaThread()
        {
            Clear();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Begin TestFileWriteViaThread");

            List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxAttempts; ++i)
            {
                var t = new Thread(TestFileWriteInt);
                t.Start(i);
                _threads.Add(t);
            }

            _threads.ForEach(T => T.Join());

            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TestFileWriteViaThread took: " + elapsedTime);
        }

        private static void TestFileWriteInt(object oIndex)
        {
            int index = (int)oIndex;
            List<string> lines = GenerateLines(index);

            File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", index), lines);
            File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"F:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}_bck.txt", index), lines);

            var text = File.ReadAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", index));
            var text1 = File.ReadAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", index));

            //File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file_test{0}.txt", index), text1);
        }

        private static  async void TestFileWriteAsync()
        {
            Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Begin TestFileWriteAsync ");
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxAttempts; ++i)
            {
                List<string> lines = GenerateLines(i);
                var allTasks = new List<Task>();

                allTasks.Add(File.WriteAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", i), lines));
                allTasks.Add(File.WriteAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"F:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}_bck.txt", i), lines));

                await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

                var allTasks1 = new List<Task<string[]>>();
                allTasks1.Add(File.ReadAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", i)));
                allTasks1.Add(File.ReadAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", i)));

                await Task.WhenAll(allTasks1);

//                await File.WriteAllLinesAsync(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file_test{0}.txt", i), allTasks1[0].Result);
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TestFileWriteAsync took: " + elapsedTime);
        }

        private static void Clear()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(string.Format(@"C:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}.txt", i));
                System.IO.File.Delete(string.Format(@"F:\Projects\DelMee\file{0}_bck.txt", i));
            }
        }


        static string buffer = new string('a', 25 * 1024 * 1024);
        private static List<string> GenerateLines(int i)
        {
            return new List<string>() { buffer };
        }
```

And the results are:

TestFileWrite took: 00:00:03.50

TestFileWriteViaThread took: 00:00:01.63

TestFileWriteAsync took: 00:00:06.78

8 Code CPU/ C and F are 2 different SSD drive 850 EVOs on 2 different SATAs.

**Update:3 - Conclusion** Looks like the File.WriteAllLinesAsync does handle well the scenario when we want to flush large amount of data. As it was pointed out from the answers bellow it is better to use FileStream directly. But still async is slower than sequential access.

But for now the fastest approach still remains if you use multi threading.

Comment: `In theory the first approach should be faster` That is an incorrect assumption. `async` is not necessarily about making things _faster_. It depends on implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753339/async-file-reading-40-times-slower-than-synchronous-or-manual-threads

Comment: @Kiko I think that the problem is that you are performing writing data to a single physical drive. If you use SATA drive than it cannot write data simultaneously. Therefore write operations itself in your code could perform sequentially.

Comment: Your question is so lacking in detail, it would be impossible for anyone to say for sure why you see the relative performance difference that you do. Both of the previous comments suggest very plausible explanations, but frankly your question cannot be provided any sort of good answer without more details and a good [mcve], at a minimum. Even then, it may not be all that novel or useful a question anyway.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev very good point. But I tried on 2 different drives and the result was Same.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It is pretty clear example, but just in case I uploaded the a simple demo + results

Comment: You're doing I/O bound work.  Pure I/O should, generally speaking, already be handled in a very efficient way by the kernel, such as [I/O completion ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_completion_port).  That aside, have you tried running your benchmark through a profiler?  It should show you exactly where that wall-clock time is being spent.

Comment: `Pure I/O should, generally speaking, already be handled in a very efficient way by the kernel` Unless the `TextWriter`, for example, spun up new tasks - https://github.com/FajarHi/corefx/blob/054c6006aaacd48ad7363d10dbd5f85803f624da/corefx-master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/TextWriter.cs#L508 .

Comment: @Kiko Could you please add to the question characteristics of you hard drives and CPU? Are drives `C` and `F` different physical (not logical) drives? I'll try later to run your test in my environment.

Comment: @Kiko you can't benchmark code like this. Your code is performing a ton of string operations that would affect performance *far more* than any difference between sync and async. Disk IO is affected by *everything* too, so performing just 5 iterations is meaningless - each runner will be completely different. Use BenchmarkDotNet instead, and check for allocation overhead. Rewrite your tests so they *all* write the same static string

Comment: @Kiko apart from that, async IO doesn't help with raw single-thread performance, it helps with *concurrency*.

Comment: In addition to everything already said, two `await  File.WriteAllLinesAsync()`, without res1 and res2, would execute sequentially (still async) and be a better match to the non-async version.

Comment: @Kiko creating raw threads has an overhead too, that's why Task.Run exists. Instead of creating a new thread, it uses an already existing one from a thread pool. Your tests count the thread creation overhead instead of just the async overhead. BenchmarkDotNet eliminates that variation by repeating each benchmark until the results stabilise.

Comment: Have you tried doing the async test sequentially? In other words to `await` each task after creating it, so that only one task is "running" at any given moment. Does this make any difference regarding the performance?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I did. Again it is slower than the other approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a known issue. If you Google, you will see heaps similar posts.

Eg https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23196

**If *fast* is the requirement for single IO operation, you should always use  sync IO as well as sync methods.**

`Write*Async` methods internally opens file stream in asynchronous IO mode, which has overhead cost compared to sync IO.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o

> However, for relatively fast I/O operations, the overhead of processing kernel I/O requests and kernel signals may make asynchronous I/O less beneficial, particularly if many fast I/O operations need to be made. In this case, synchronous I/O would be better.

Also asynchronous methods in `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` may have issues with small buffer size. The default buffer size for writing to file stream is 4KB, which is way too small than file size (25MB to 50MB). Despite the buffer size seems working for sync methods fine, but it exaggerates the overhead cost incurred by async methods.

See this [line](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamWriter.cs,709), the method yields thread every time when buffer is full. If you are writing a 25MB file with the default 4096 bytes buffer, this happens 6400 times.

To optimize that, if the entire file is in memory, the buffer size could be set to the file size to reduce context switching and synchronization between each write and flush.

If you open `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` with different buffer sizes in your code and run the tests for `Write` and `WriteAsync`, you will see difference. If the buffer size is identical to the file size, the difference between sync and async methods is very small.

For example:

```
// 4KB buffer sync stream
using (var stream = new FileStream(
    path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 
    4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(str25mb);
    }
}

// 25MB buffer sync stream
using (var stream = new FileStream(
    path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 
    25 * 1024 * 1024, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(str25mb);
    }
}

// 4KB buffer async stream
using (var stream = new FileStream(
    path,
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read,
    4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await writer.WriteAsync(str25mb);
}

// 25MB buffer async stream
using (var stream = new FileStream(
    path,
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read,
    25 * 1024 * 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await writer.WriteAsync(str25mb);
}
```

Result (I run each test 10 times) was:

```
TestFileWriteWithLargeBuffer took: 00:00:00.9291647
TestFileWriteWithLargeBufferAsync took: 00:00:01.1950127
TestFileWrite took: 00:00:01.5251026
TestFileWriteAsync took: 00:00:03.6913877
```

Comment: You are right, but still Async is 2 times slower than non-async. The same proportion like WriteAllLines.

Comment: The `WriteAllLines` and `WriteAllLinesAsync` internally use `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` with small buffer, so that is why the async method is twice slower than the sync method. But this only happens when writing large files when needing to flush the buffer many times. In this case, you could optimize the write operation by using a `FileStream` with large size buffer.

Comment: In terms of *async is slower than sync*. This is true for any single IO operation as per the MSDN docs says.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong with my first answer since not used wait for `Task.WhenAll` when tried to remove `async` from the `TestFileWriteAsync`.

I've [fixed test](https://gist.github.com/oleksabor/f5ad3e4e7e257ba91be2b3d056c4d33a) and it shows that `File.Write*Async` is really slower.

```
Begin TestFileWriteAsync
TestFileWriteAsync took: 00:00:13.7128699
Begin TestFileWrite
TestFileWrite took: 00:00:01.5734895
Begin TestFileWriteViaThread
TestFileWriteViaThread took: 00:00:00.8322218
```

Please excuse me

PS I've checked the Async methods source code.

Looks like `File.WriteAllLinesAsync` and `File.WriteAllTextAsync` uses the same [InternalWriteAllTextAsync](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs,21be7584cf46b509) that copies the part of the original buffer one more time

```
buffer = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(DefaultBufferSize);
int count = contents.Length;
int index = 0;
while (index < count)
{
 int batchSize = Math.Min(DefaultBufferSize, count - index);
 contents.CopyTo(index, buffer, 0, batchSize);
#if MS_IO_REDIST
 await sw.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, batchSize).ConfigureAwait(false);
#else
 await sw.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>(buffer, 0, batchSize), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
#endif
```

The `contents.CopyTo(index, buffer, 0, batchSize);` is the line that copies the part of the original data buffer.

You can try with `File.WriteAllBytesAsync` it takes data buffer "as is" and does not execute additional copy operation:

```
Begin TestFileWriteAsync
TestFileWriteAsync took: 00:00:00.7741439
Begin TestFileWrite
TestFileWrite took: 00:00:00.5772008
Begin TestFileWriteViaThread
TestFileWriteViaThread took: 00:00:00.4457552
```

WriteAllBytesAsync [test source code](https://gist.github.com/oleksabor/f5ad3e4e7e257ba91be2b3d056c4d33a#file-tstv3bytearray-cs)

Comment: N.P. Yes I've noticed this and updated my comment + reduced the overhead caused by buffer generation, just to make it clear.

Comment: @Kiko please try with `WriteAllBytesAsync` - it is the same fast as the `WriteAllBytes` method. I've updated my answer with part of .Net Core source code that can explain why `WriteAllLinesAsync` is so slow. And here is [test v3 with byte array source code](https://gist.github.com/oleksabor/f5ad3e4e7e257ba91be2b3d056c4d33a#file-tstv3bytearray-cs)

Comment: Hi @oleksa, thanks for you analysis.  I am still trying to realise what I am seeing :). I see this function is very dummy implemented. M$ goal is to write write on chunks but they could simple use use **WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count)** with proper offsets, instead of copy the buffer + to use ReadOnlyMemory.

Comment: I don't think that line of code "copies the part of the original buffer one more time". That line of code copies `string` to a `char[]` then the next line writes the `char[]` to stream. The sync method writes `string` to stream, where it is also copied to a `char[]` buffer.

Comment: @weichch The `WriteAllBytesAsync` is the same fast as `WriteAllBytes` so I do not think that the problem is in the async approach. For example, `InternalWriteAllTextAsync` uses `string.CopyTo` that moves data between memory using the [Buffer.Memmove<T>](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Buffer.cs,6801135fbcd55471). The `InternalWriteAllLines` uses [Buffer.Memmove](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Buffer.cs,622f81c70728ec1d). I don't know what is `RuntimeHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferences<string>()` result. Will it do the `BulkMoveWithWriteBarrier` or not ?

Comment: @weichch I've just found that `RuntimeHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferences<string>()` result is true. That means `InternalWriteAllTextAsync` causes `void Memmove<T>` to use `BulkMoveWithWriteBarrier`. This is actual difference between  `InternalWriteAllTextAsync` and `InternalWriteAllLines`. The `InternalWriteAllLines` uses [Stream.Write()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamWriter.cs,715bd5de78456219) that calls [Buffer.Memmove](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Buffer.cs,622f81c70728ec1d)

Comment: `WriteAllTextAsync` runs as fast as `WriteAllText` on my machine. The only difference before your and my tests is I run sync version first.

Comment: Interestingly, if using the OP's data and test, `WriteAllTextAsync` is indeed slower than `WriteAllText`, but my 4096 bytes data wouldn't give me the same result.

Comment: @weichch I've tried to test with 100KB buffer and the results are `TestFileWriteAsync 00.2640504` and `TestFileWrite 00.0281505`. And `TestFileWriteAsync took: 00:00:01.0431329` with `TestFileWrite took: 00:00:00.1100321` for 1MB buffer.