# How do I use the spaceship operator in a switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, c++20, spaceship-operator

The new `<=>` operator makes writing code more convenient and it can save some performance if the comparison algorithm is non-trivial, because it doesn't need to be repeated two times to get the full ordering.

Or at least I though so when I learned about it.
However, when I try to use it in practice, in a `switch` statement, it doesn't work.

This code doesn't compile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void compare_values(int x, int y)
{
    switch (x <=> y)
    {
    case std::strong_ordering::less:
        std::cout << "is less\n";
        break;
    case std::strong_ordering::greater:
        std::cout << "is greater\n";
        break;
    case std::strong_ordering::equal:
        std::cout << "is equal\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

The compiler shows an error suggesting that the value returned by `<=>` cannot be used in a `switch`:

```
<source>: In function 'void compare_values(int, int)':
<source>:5:15: error: switch quantity not an integer
    5 |     switch (x <=> y)
      |             ~~^~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qc7exnG59))

I would guess that using the spaceship operator in switch is a pretty basic, obvious and common use case, so there is probably some trick to making it work. I cannot figure it out, though.

How can I fix this code?

Comment: The error is as stated:  *error: switch quantity not an integer* -- A `switch` statement must have an integral value.  `<=>` retuns a [std::strong_ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering), which is not an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the spaceship operator (formally known as [three-way comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)) **does not return an ingeral type**, and therefore cannot be used in a `switch-case` statement.

In this case of comparing types like `int`s, the spaceship operator returns a [`std::strong_ordering`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering).

*(A side note: as you can see in the documentation there are cases where the spaceship operator returns a `std::partial_ordering` but this isn't an integral type either).*

You can use it in an `if-else` statement instead.

If you prefer to use a `switch-case`, you can use a trivial utility that converts the `std::strong_ordering` to an integral type with some predefined values.
Returning -1/0/1 in this case will be quite natural:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int strong_ordering_to_int(std::strong_ordering o)
{
    if (o == std::strong_ordering::less)    return -1;
    if (o == std::strong_ordering::greater) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void compare_values(int x, int y)
{
    switch (strong_ordering_to_int(x <=> y))
    {
    case -1:
        std::cout << "is less\n";
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "is greater\n";
        break;
    case 0:
        std::cout << "is equal\n";
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    compare_values(2, 3);
    compare_values(3, 2);
    compare_values(3, 3);
}
```

Output:

```
is less
is greater
is equal
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h9nMva6dz)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the committee didn't think about the `switch` when designing this operator.

Comment: C++ standards committee is prone to leaving out common use cases of new features or how they'll interact with existing language constructs, for a long time.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa I don't want to speculate about the committee's reasons. Anyway if somebody will come up with a better solution, I'll be glad to learn.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa: The committee explicitly did not want the ordering operators to be numbers (for very good reasons), but `switch` can only work with numbers. This is the result.

Comment: @TanveerBadar -- people who don't participate in standardization are prone to baselessly ascribing all sorts of stupidity to those who do the actual work.

Comment: Several of my coworkers are committee members, and the amount of scrutiny and agony over minutia is incredible.  That's why things like Stepanov's STL, Zverovich's fmt, Niebler's ranges, and various Boost components that become standardized often (inevitably?) are a subset of the original basis, and have their semantics tweaked or wholesale changed so that the proposal fits in with C++'s language goals & north star.

Comment: I would be more inclined to believe in this attention to detail if it were not for the abomination called "co-routines", whose only purpose is to bless a threading model that will not suck on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: If that's true, then maybe somebody else should have put in the work. All of the other alternative coroutine proposals had basically no implementation experience. They were all hypothetical, and in one case, they realized that their theoretical idea couldn't actually be implemented. Say what you will about `co_await` coroutines, they actually *work*, which is more than you can say for any of the proposed alternatives. A proposal that is proven viable, does the purported job, and that job is useful is going to be picked over something that maybe will work out... eventually.

Comment: Has it occured to you, @NicolBolas, an alternative possibility: that co-routines are a solution in search of a problem? Perhaps the reason why noone else cared, much, about co-routines is because nobody but Microsoft gave a flying fig about them? Only Microsoft desperately needed them because regualr threads on MS-Windows suck.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*Perhaps the reason why noone else cared, much, about co-routines is because nobody but Microsoft gave a flying fig about them?*" Considering the fact that almost every language made today has some form of coroutine in it (some of them taking deliberate inspiration from C#'s `await`, others going about it their own way), I would say that this speculation is without foundation.

Comment: So, your specific example of coroutines' popularity is ... another Microsoft platform. I don't deny that coroutines are popular in Microsoftverse. Because that's its only threading model that does not suck.

Comment: @NicolBolas saying all the other proposals were trash, so they implemented the least trash one is not quite the winning solution I would have wanted. I guess nobody else figured it was something worth adding, hence the lack of proposals?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*So, your specific example of coroutines' popularity is ... another Microsoft platform.*" I cited C# specifically because it's the originator of the `await`-style of corotuines. But `await`-style coroutines exist in Python, taking direct inspiration from C#. Go, Kotlin, Lua, and Rust all have coroutines of various sorts. And those are just the ones I checked via a Google search or personal knowledge. Coroutines are a normal thing for programming languages to have.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: "*saying all the other proposals were trash*" But I didn't say that, so the rest of your comment is meaningless. They weren't *proven*, while `co_await` was. I rather liked one or two of the alternatives, but the people behind those proposals didn't put in the legwork to actually prove that they could be implemented. They were pure paper proposals, and for something as complex at a compiler level like coroutines, you can't just throw paper in the standard and hope it works out.

Comment: "Of various sorts". C++ is not C#, Go, Kotlin, Lua, or Rust. If something makes sense in other languages it doesn't automatically mean that it must makes sense in C++, too. I picked one of randomly: Lua. The first hit for "lua multiple threads" points to https://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html which implements multithreading ... via coroutines. Looks like no real multithreading in Lua. That's fine. All it has is coroutines. Wonderful. Different languages may very well be suitable for different tasks. So: what other non-Microsoftian language has both coroutines and real threading (excepting C++ now)?

Comment: @NicolBolas and yet your argument is "the other ones were no good". At no point do you say whether the accepted one *was* any good. As others have suggested, the design appears not to be, even if it was a working proposal. Imagine if garbage collection (the hot thing of its day) was suggested as a full implementation. Coroutines are hot right now, that doesn't mean they're ideal. Even javascript has them.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: "*and yet your argument is 'the other ones were no good'.*" If you put quotes around what someone says, it should actually be an exact thing they said. Stop putting words into people's mouths. I did not assess the quality of any of the others, only their *maturity* (ie: proven to work).

Comment: @NicolBolas I know they are trash, all the code I've seen use them is written "await MyAsyncFnAsync()". The only time I saw real coroutines used was when I wrote one to load DB data because MS said it was faster. It was a *tenth* of the perf of the boring old-fashioned way. Today I see MS reports of file reading that's [half the perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074203/c-sharp-performance-comparison-async-vs-non-async-text-file-io-operation-via-r) of sync. Co-routines are overengineered trash ways of doing nothing (as nobody seems to use them actually async) but slower.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*So: what other non-Microsoftian language has both coroutines and real threading*" ... I mentioned several. Go, Kotlin, Rust, Java all have "both coroutines and real threading". I'm sorry you "randomly" picked the one language I mentioned that didn't provide threading functionality. Also, you seem to be ignoring why I brought them up. You claimed that "that co-routines are a solution in search of a problem", that "noone else cared". I brought those examples up to disprove that notion. That's the only reason why they're relevant.

Comment: Hm... So I picked the first one on your list, Go. Plugged in ye olde search engine. First hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416122/is-golang-good-to-use-in-multithreaded-application -- well, well, it seems that Go threads are ...not real threads, but ... kind like coroutines. I maintain my position: with actual execution threads, coroutines are a solution in search of a problem. And, yes, I picked Lua randomly. This time I just picked the first one on the list. I think I'll go I random next time...

Comment: @NicolBolas Java does not have coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers do a bad job of optimizing using if to extract the value of the ordering types(gcc/clang/MSVC) see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P7scbPqGT.

```
to_integral(std::__1::strong_ordering):
        xor     ecx, ecx
        test    dil, dil
        setne   cl
        cmp     dil, -1
        mov     eax, 255
        cmovne  eax, ecx
        ret
```

The best way to get good codegen(see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b8Pf1GErP)

```
to_integral(std::__1::strong_ordering):
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

is to play on the big 3 implementations using an underlying char value member.  One can easily add static_asserts with the strong_ordering/weak_ordering values to ensure this.  The following will optimize to at worst a copy.
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4En7sbsoE

```cpp
#include <compare>
#include <bit>

enum class cmp_result: signed char { less = -1, equivalent = 0, equal = 0, greater = 1 };

constexpr cmp_result to_integral( std::strong_ordering x ) {
    return std::bit_cast<cmp_result>( x );
}
constexpr cmp_result to_integral( std::weak_ordering x ) {
    return std::bit_cast<cmp_result>( x );
}

static_assert( to_integral( std::strong_ordering::less ) == cmp_result::less );
static_assert( to_integral( std::strong_ordering::equal ) == cmp_result::equal );
static_assert( to_integral( std::strong_ordering::greater ) == cmp_result::greater );

static_assert( to_integral( std::weak_ordering::less ) == cmp_result::less );
static_assert( to_integral( std::weak_ordering::equivalent ) == cmp_result::equivalent );
static_assert( to_integral( std::weak_ordering::greater ) == cmp_result::greater );
```

With this we can now efficiently switch over the spaceship operator.

```cpp
void compare_values(int x, int y)
{
    switch (to_integral(x <=> y))
    {
    case cmp_result::less:
        std::cout << "is less\n";
        break;
    case cmp_result::greater:
        std::cout << "is greater\n";
        break;
    case cmp_result::equal:
        std::cout << "is equal\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the whole OP's example will be https://godbolt.org/z/8j1T1xjGY

Comment: Does the standard guarantee that these values will fit into `signed char`? If for example in some compiler `std::strong_ordering::less` would happen to be `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, we would have a signed underflow which is an undefined behavior.

Comment: OK, I see you've used `std::bit_cast` which won't be a singed underflow but it still won't work in that scenario.

Comment: One can static assert on the values.  I've done it for libc++/libstdc++/MS STL and they are all -1,0,1
static_assert( to_integral( std::strong_ordering::less ) == -1 ); 
// for strong_ordering/weak_ordering less/equal/equivilent/greater .  But the implementations have pretty much done it this way.  This isn't going to be std C++, but coded to the implmentations.

Comment: For any platform where this assumption is true, I would also assume the compiler to convert the corresponding `if`/`else if` chain (as used in the other answer) to something algebraic anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux they don't, at least currently.  I updated with examples of how bad the codegen is.  The differences is 2 branches and returning a constant compared to returning the parameter(which would turn into a cast like expression)

Comment: Maybe instead of `static_assert` we could `if constexpr` it and use the `if` chain approach as a fallback.